# When using ES6 import statement, is there a way to protect against items being undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
import {
  foobar1,
  foobar2,
  foobor3,  //typo!  this key doesn't exist in the module.

} from './module_file.js'


console.log(foobar1, foobar2, foobar3)  //EXPLODES
```

One of the most frequent silly mistakes I make when using the new ES6 style import statement is that I'll have a typo in one of the keys in object destructuring.  I can't think of a single instance where I'd ever want a value in a destructuring assignment to be `undefined`.  Is there any way to force the import statement to fail-fast if one of the items I'm trying to import is undefined?

ie:

```
 import {
  doesntExistInModule  //EXPLODE NOW!  
} from './module_file.js'
```

Comment: I think the only way to do this would a be a complicated linter. Check ESlint plugins for something like this.

Comment: Or write your own Babel plugin which wraps imports in an additional check and throws an error if they're undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module stuff in the spec is pretty gnarly, but I believe a real implementation will throw a `SyntaxError` at [15.2.1.16.4 ModuleDeclarationInstantiation( ) Concrete Method step 12.d.iii](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-moduledeclarationinstantiation) in that case. Since there are no legit implementations I don't know if you're talking about a way to do it in transpiled code in the meantime, or if you don't realize that's the case and will be satisfied to know it'll work that way eventually. There's been talk before of trying to implement that kind of check in Babel, but as far as I know nothing's actually been done to that effect. Babel compiles each module in isolation.

Also, this is *not* object destructuring, it just has similar syntax.

Answer (score 4):

> - There is no hook allowing a module to run some code before its    dependencies load. This means that modules have no control over how
>     their dependencies are loaded.
> - There is no error recovery for import errors. An app may have hundreds of    modules in it, and if anything fails to load or link,
>     nothing runs. You can’t import in a try/catch block. (The upside here
>     is that because the system is so static, webpack can detect those
>     errors for you at compile time.)

For more details, [read it out](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/)