# Javascript promise "then" always runs even though the promise failed to execute

Tags: javascript, promise, deferred

I want the third "then" to not be executed when the second "then" is called. However, it still calls the third "then" even though the promise is rejected (the second "then" is called) and the code returns "rejected" and then "undefined". How to not run the third "then" so the "undefined" won't show up?

```
var FirstPromise = function() {

  let promiseme = new Promise(function(res, rej) {

    if ('a' == 'b') {
      res(1);
    } else {
      rej('rejected');
    }
  })

  return promiseme;
};

function succeddcallback(msg) {
  return msg * 2;
}

function errorcallback(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}

FirstPromise()
  .then(succeddcallback, null)
  .then(null, errorcallback)
  .then(function(succedded) {
    console.log(succedded);
  }, function(failed) {
    console.log(failed);
  })
```

Answer (score 9):

That's because you caught the error in the `catch` statement - i.e. `.then(null,errorcallback)` - and you never threw another error or returned a rejected promise in it.

...which is the same as returning a resolved promise with a value of undefined, which is why your next `.then` executes the success callback.

If you want your error to propagate to a subsequent `.catch` or `.then(null,fn)`, then your `errorcallback` must throw (or return a rejected promise):

```
function errorcallback(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  throw new Error(msg); //or (return Promise.reject(msg);
}
```

Keep in mind that in every `.catch` (or `.then(null,fn)` you have to re-throw (or return a rejected promise) in order for subsequent error callbacks to get called.

Comment: @januaryananda - rephrased - you used `.then(null,errorcallback)` which is the same as `.catch`

Comment: @januaryananda you have to re-throw in your catch function. Or just not catch it.

Comment: @januaryananda - I've edited the answer to show how to do that.

Comment: @januaryananda Here is an website which explains how promise chaining works. https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Comment: Can I completely stop the third "then" execution (not showing rejected or resolved mesaage) when the second "then" is fired up?

Comment: @januaryananda - as long as your `errorcallback` throws or returns a rejected Promise, you can remove the third `then`'s second parameter entirely. The third `then`'s resolved (first) function would never get called, in this circumstance, because the promise created it before it in the chain gets rejected.

Comment: What I read before, if the first "then" is firing the rejectedFN, the second "then" won't be executed at all. But my code still runs the second "then" even when the first "then" is firing the rejectedFN.. Can you correct my understanding ? So confused

Comment: @januaryananda - I've corrected it several times in the comments and in the answer. **if you're errorcallback does not throw an error**, then a resolved promise will be returned and the first parameter (the success callback) to any `.then` after it in the chain will be called instead of the `rejectedFN`, which is exactly what is happening. Forget about what you're reading for a moment and try the code in my answer, the lightbulb will come on eventually.

Comment: I see, is it because of this -> and returns a new promise resolving to the return value of the called handler, or to its original settled value if the promise was not handled